# Include personal scripts & algorithms in scientific paper

Tags: publications, research-process, paper-submission, review-articles

as the title said I want to include a lot of scripts I wrote in scientific paper but how I do that do I upload them In GitHub & then cite them or include them as additional materials at the end of the paper.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes to both, though providing code through a service like GitHub may be preferable as you can obtain a citable DOI and your readers will know where to find updated code, if any. Figshare is another option. Providing code in your supplement can provide redundancy, especially if you would like readers to cite your paper when they use your code. See Rule 8 under these [Ten Simple Rules for Taking Advantage of Git and GitHub](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004947) for more details.

Comment: OK that's good..If you have any additional informations I would like to know.

Comment: Also if I'm not wrong  GitHub will cease from existence in 2020..So what happen to my scripts!

Comment: Nothing lasts forever. You can, of course, host the code at a place you control, as long as readers know where it is and you have a way to ensure it will remain accessible.

Comment: Let's assume I host my scripts in my Owen website,is it possible to get a citable DOI?

Comment: No. You will be responsible for making material on your own site accessible and citable.